# Oracle Apex - image in report is not updated on region refresh

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have an interactive/classic report with a column that shows images.
The row in the report can be edited as usual with a modal dialog.

But when I replace existing image it is not updated in the report even though all other fields do. I can also see that the numerical representation of the image is getting updated. Only the visualization of the image stays the same.

Also, when saving and refreshing the whole page, the correct image is showing up.

[image]

[image: report]

The query that creates the report:

```
select  
    ID,
    APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(15,p_value => ID) as "Select",
    DESCRIPTION,
    dbms_lob.getlength(BLOB_CONTENT) as "Image" 
from UPLOADED_IMAGES
```

The image column Type is "Display image"

Why the images don't get updated on region refresh?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide details as to how you're displaying the image? There may be some caching going on, and this might be circumvented by suffixing ?v=#APP_UNIQUE_PAGE_ID# to the URL

Comment: I added to my question the report query and the column type (Display image).
As for "v=#APP_UNIQUE_PAGE_ID#" I'm not sure I understand, but the image is not displayed with URL

Comment: My suggestion depended on how you're rendering the file, not relevant in your case.

Answer (score 1):

So I changed the query that creates the Image column to:

```
nvl2(BLOB_CONTENT,
     apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P3040_BLOB_CONTENT',ID,null,'inline'),
     null) as BLOB_CONTENT
```

As written in several guides

(Also need:

- HTML Expression --> `<img src="#Image#" height="75px">`
- Escape special characters --> 'No')

and now the refresh works. Still don't explain why the other way doesn't, but it's good enough.